# Autofac ContainerBuilder.Build takes avg 2000 ms

Tags: serialization, autofac

I have about 1000 classes and interfaces spread in about 10 assemblies and I'm using `Autofac.Module` to register the dependencies and mostly classes are being registered using `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes().Where(SomeCondition).AsImplementedInterfaces()`

The problem is that the call to `containerBuilder.Build()` is taking about 2000ms.

Is there any performance tips or debugging advice to reduce this time?

I've read this link: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/BestPractices and I'm following mostly advices there.

I thought I could save the state of the built container with some cache (using BinaryFormatter, for example) and just recreate the container when the dependencies changes (or the cache invalidated). But to do this, IContainer would need to be marked with `[Serializable]` and I discarted this option because as some folks advice, container has reference to other fields and classes.

So, what can I do find the problem and reduce this time? Because the IIS take down the application after some idle time and then, even if there's no deploy, my app takes about 4, 5 seconds to start up (2 seconds because the container and 2 seconds because the creation of SessionFactory from NHibernate).

I'm using Autofac version 3.0.0.

Comment: Making the container serializable is impossible. A registration often has reference to a Func<> which could reference variables/fields/etc. outside the function block.

Comment: Yes, I discarded this option. Tks!

Comment: If the performance is more important than the convenience of assembly scanning, you could register each type individually using a lambda function. This would alleviate some of the reflection Autofac does.

Comment: Yeah..., I thought that, but then I got lazy when I thought the number of the classes that I will need to register =(. I was just hoping that would exist something in container's configuration that would do the trick. I will register the types individually in some big modules with a lot classes and see if the time reduces.

Comment: You could write a small app that iterates over the registrations in your container and generates the c# code to register each one explicitly.

Comment: Uhnnn... Good idea! Tks, @JimBolla! 
I will try that.